# Drupal 8 : Get a config settings value being stored in blocs

Tags: 8, forms, configuration

I have create a block with a form and stored something i called 'submit_action_amu_dud_form_block_settings'

```
 public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $this->configuration['submit_action_amu_dud_form_block_settings'] = $form_state->getValue('submit_action_amu_dud_form_block_settings');

 }
```

in a method of the same class i can retrieve the value

```
      $config = $this->getConfiguration();
      $my_stored value=$config['submit_action_amu_dud_form_block_settings']
```

how can i get it from . module hook_form_alter callback ?

```
    function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {


if ($form_id == 'amu_dud_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_submit_method';        
}
}

 function my_submit_method(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

//$my_stored_value=??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the block if your outside of the class, for that you need it's id.

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($bid);
$my_stored_value = $block->get('settings')['submit_action_amu_dud_form_block_settings'];
```

The id can be found in it's annotation if it's custom: `@Block( * id = "my_fancy_block_id"`. If there are several instances of the block this may be altered and can be looked up in the DB, or the block config admin section - check the urls there.

Comment: do u know how to get $bid ? is it no what i have defined in the block class  comment* @Block(
 *  id = "amu_dud_form_block",

Comment: yes - it is -  ;)

Comment: the $block->configuration(....) does not work for instance of block $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('amududformblock_3');

Comment: and is it not possible to load the configuration for the my_fancy_block_id loaded in the page? (not a static value put in the module code )

Answer (score 0):

thanks to remy i have been able to retrieve the value from an instance of block this way:

```
//instance of block bid found in db
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('my_blockinstance_bid');
$block_settings = $block->get('settings');
$url=$block_settings['my_stored_setting'];
```

The problem remain then , when having mutliple instance of blocs, to load a block config dynamically corresponding to the settings value that have been stored for the block being displayed on the page ?

Comment: every instance should have an unique id - thanks for the working code, I updated my answer too, as I just 'guessed'